# Is there a better way to find conditional last values in a table?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table called `t`:

| user_id | val | tstamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2021-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 1 | b | 2021-01-01 10:01:00 |
| 1 | X | 2021-01-01 10:02:00 |
| 1 | X | 2021-01-01 10:04:00 |
| 1 | a | 2021-01-01 10:05:00 |
| 1 | X | 2021-01-01 10:06:00 |
| 2 | X | 2021-01-01 10:07:00 |
| 2 | X | 2021-01-01 10:08:00 |
| 3 | a | 2021-01-01 10:07:00 |
| 3 | a | 2021-01-01 10:08:00 |
| 4 |  | 2021-01-01 10:08:00 |
| 5 | c | 2021-01-01 10:09:00 |
| 5 |  | 2021-01-01 10:10:00 |
| 6 |  | 2021-01-01 10:09:00 |
| 6 | X | 2021-01-01 10:10:00 |
| 7 | d | 2021-01-01 10:09:00 |
| 7 | X | 2021-01-01 10:10:00 |

from which I need the latest (by `tstamp` ) non-null value from `val` for each user that is not `X`. If there is no other value for a user other than `X`, it should just be `X` (like user 2). If there was no value for a user whatsoever, it should remain `NULL` (like for user 4). The intended outcome for the above table is the following:

| user_id | last_val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | X |
| 3 | a |
| 4 |  |
| 5 | c |
| 6 | X |
| 7 | d |

I'm mainly looking for a way to do this with the least amount of CTEs necessary as I already have a solution for this, which goes as follows:

```
with user_values as ( 
    select 
        user_id, 
        count(distinct val) as types_of_vals, 
        coalesce(boolor_agg(val = 'X'),false) as has_value_x 
    from t 
    group by 1
),
user_last_value as ( 
    select distinct 
        user_id, 
        last_value(val) over (partition by user_id order by tstamp) as last_value_without_x 
    from t 
    where val!='X'
)
select distinct 
    user_id, 
    case 
        when types_of_vals=0 then null 
        when (types_of_vals=1 and has_value_x) then 'X' 
    else 
        last_value_without_x 
    end as last_val
from t
left join user_values using (user_id)
left join user_last_value using (user_id)
order by user_id;
```

This seems to be too complicated, but it produces the intended outcome. I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this.

An alternative way for it could be by

```
select 
    *, 
    last_value(val) ignore 'X' over (partition by user_id order by tstamp) as last_value_without_x, -- this won't work 
    last_value(val) ignore nulls over (partition by user_id order by tstamp) as last_value_without_nulls
from t
```

and then in a later CTE I can coalesce the `last_value_without_x` and `last_value_without_nulls` to arrive at what's needed, but unfortunately, arbitrary values cannot be ignored by `last_value()`.

I'm using Snowflake if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `row_number()` for this:

```
select user_id, val as last_val
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id
                                order by (val is not null) desc,
                                         (val = 'X') desc,
                                         timestamp desc)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can use explicit conversions for the `order by` (i.e. `(val = 'x')::int desc`) if you want to be explicit about the type conversion.

Comment: I consider this one to be the most readable, complete, easy-to-follow solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `NULLIF`:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, NULLIF(val, 'X') AS val_without_x FROM t
)
select *, 
    last_value(val_without_x) ignore nulls 
          over (partition by user_id order by tstamp) as last_value_without_x, 
    last_value(val) ignore nulls 
          over (partition by user_id order by tstamp) as last_value_without_nulls
from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select user_id, val last_val from (
        select user_Id, val, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by tstamp desc) rn
        from t
        where val !='x' or (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.user_id=t.user_id and t2.val !='X' )=0
    ) x
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

with the data:

```
WITH data(user_id, val, tstamp) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (1, 'a', '2021-01-01 10:00:00'),
        (1, 'b', '2021-01-01 10:01:00'),
        (1, 'X', '2021-01-01 10:02:00'),
        (1, 'X', '2021-01-01 10:04:00'),
        (1, 'a', '2021-01-01 10:05:00'),
        (1, 'X', '2021-01-01 10:06:00'),
        (2, 'X', '2021-01-01 10:07:00'),
        (2, 'X', '2021-01-01 10:08:00'),
        (3, 'a', '2021-01-01 10:07:00'),
        (3, 'a', '2021-01-01 10:08:00'),
        (4, null,'2021-01-01 10:08:00'),
        (5, 'c', '2021-01-01 10:09:00'),
        (5, null,'2021-01-01 10:10:00'),
        (6, null,'2021-01-01 10:09:00'),
        (6, 'X', '2021-01-01 10:10:00'),
        (7, 'd', '2021-01-01 10:09:00'),
        (7, 'X', '2021-01-01 10:10:00')
)
```

the following gives you the correct answers and is a little bit shorter that Gordon's answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    user_id, 
    LAST_VALUE(val) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY val != 'X', tstamp)
FROM data;
```

and if you don't like the DISTINCT it the ROW_NUMBER can be moved to the [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html#qualify) and still be a single layer select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    user_id, 
    val
FROM data
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTION BY user_id ORDER BY val != 'X' DESC NULLS LAST, tstamp DESC) = 1
```

Also the sorting my NULLs change be handled via the [ORDER BY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/order-by.html#order-by) of the VAL sort with NULLS LAST